# Flutter - PageView - Only scroll when you swipe on top of a specific component instead of any location of the page

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-pageview

Totally new to flutter, less than 10h on it.

I have a PageView handing 3 pages, it scrolls horizontally through them perfectly.

But I would like to change the "allowed swipe" area. I don't want to let the user change the pages scrolling from any position of the page, but instead, for example, just let him scroll the pages if he swipes on the AppBar component for example.

I saw the PageView has the applyTo method, I'm just lost about how to give to it the ID(keys) or the appBar to see if this will work.

Is there a way of achieving this "only scroll if the user swipes on the component X"?

---

**Edit 1**

Solution suggested by **[Alberto Miola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2178238/alberto-miola)** works like a charm, here is my code (I had to implement from PreferredSizeWidget since is required to modify the AppBar).

```
class GestureDetectorForAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final double height;
  final AppBar appbar;
  final GestureDragUpdateCallback onPanUpdate;

  GestureDetectorForAppBar({
    Key key,
    this.appbar,
    this.onPanUpdate,
    @required this.height,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(child: this.appbar, onPanUpdate: this.onPanUpdate,);
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(height);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need to "block" the swipe gesture on the `PageView` itself using [NeverScrollableScrollPhysics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html):

```
PageView(
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  children: [...],
  controller: ...
);
```

Note the usage of a `const` constructor. In this way you won't be able to move among pages with your finger. In Flutter you have **widgets** and not **components**.

---

Give a look at the [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) widget which can be used to listen on swipes and change the currently visible content of your `PageView`. It can be used to detect swipes:

```
GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (data) {
    if (data.delta.dx > 0) {
      // right swipe
    } 

    if (data.delta.dx < 0) {
      // right swipe
    }
  }
);
```

---

In order, I suggest you to first read about `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in the official documentation. It's used to "block" scrolling behaviors. Then, use `GestureDetector()` to wrap the widget you want to be used as a "scroll director" (the one that actually scrolls the pages).

Inside `onPanUpdate` you'll deal with the [`animateToPage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController/animateToPage.html) method of the `PageController` to change the currently visible page.

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect the result of your solution, works like a charm!

Comment: I want to make us aware of the comments: "// right swipe" and "// right swipe" 

Comment: How to keep track if a page is already being animated? in case user swipes again in that time